# error "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations"

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm getting a couple of errors,  [E1] "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations", [E2] "Use of undeclared identifier used", and [E3] "Expected a class name or namespace".

```
#ifndef MAIN_SAVITCH_SEQUENCE_H
#define MAIN_SAVITCH_SEQUENCE_H

    template <class T>
    class sequence
    {
    public:
        // TYPEDEFS and MEMBER CONSTANTS
        typedef T value_type;
        static const int CAPACITY = 30;
        // CONSTRUCTOR
        sequence( );
        // MEMBER FUNCTIONS
        void showSequence();
        void attach(value_type entry);
        value_type current( );
        void remove_current( );
        int size( );

    private:
        value_type data[CAPACITY];
        int used;

    };
    template <class T>
[E3]        sequence::sequence( )
    {
[E2]        used = 0;
    }
    template <class value_type>
[E3]    void sequence::attach(value_type entry)
    {
        data[used++] = entry;
    }

    sequence::value_type sequence::current( )
    //replace sequence::value_type with typename value_type for your template
    {
        return data[used-1];
    }

    void sequence::remove_current( )
    {
        used--;
    }

    int sequence::size( )
    {
        return used;
    }

    void sequence::showSequence()
    {
        std::string display = "";
        for (int i = 0; i<used; i++)
            std::cout << data[i] << "\n";

    }

#endif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply define function inside template class

```
template <class T>
class sequence
{
   //...
   sequence() : used(0) // define function inside template class.
   {
   }
   //...
}
```

Or you need to add `template <class T>` and `<T>` before every function defined outside the template declaration:

```
template <class T>
sequence<T>::sequence( )
^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    used = 0;
}

template <class value_type>
void sequence<T>::attach(value_type entry)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    data[used++] = entry;
}

template <class T> 
typename sequence<T>::value_type sequence<T>::current( )   
         ^^^^^^^^ // 1. value_type comes from sequence template, so you need to specify sequence<T>
^^^^^^^
// 2. sequence<T>::value_type type depends on template parameter, so typename is needed
{
    return data[used-1];
}
```

How to use it:

```
sequence<int> test;
         ^^^^ // sequence is a template, you need to specify a type
```

Comment: Inside the class definition, these are implicit and not necessary while outside they are, correct?

Comment: when define them inside template class, they are not needed.

Comment: You wouldn't have a place to put them inside the class, it wouldn't make sense

Comment: This fixed a lot of errors, thank you. Do you know where I went wrong with:
    `template <class T>
    typename value_type sequence<T>::current( )
    {
        return data[used-1];
    }`?

Comment: Does my updated answer with `current()` help you? `value_type` needs to be from sequence<T> and it's type depend on template parameter

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you so much for your help billz!